# Analyzing/designing positive feedback amplifier

Tags: design, oscillator, circuit-analysis, voltage-divider

I've been searching all around to find a tutorial on analyzing/designing a positive feedback amplifier, especially a single transistor in common collector mode, but with no luck...

So, lets say I have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdSvGQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I was able to design the DC part of the oscillator, the operating point. But I just cant get my head around, how to design the AC part.

How would I calculate the values for the positive feedback capacitive divider network? Also, is there any universal way of analyzing transistor feedback circuits? I would really appreciate a step by step guide.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*How would I calculate the values for the positive feedback capacitive divider network? Also, is there any universal way of analyzing transistor feedback circuits? I would really appreciate a step by step guide.*"

What is your intention for positive feedback? For normal amplification purposes we use negative feedback (dc and ac). There is one application only which uses positive signal feedback: Harmonic oscillators.

Regarding an "universal way" for analyzing feedback loops: At first, you must identify the feedback loop. There are some special methods to calculate/simulate the gain within this loop. This "loop gain LG" is used to prove/justify stability properties of the circuit. By the way, this "loop gain" LG also appears in the denominator D of the closed-loop gain function (D=1-LG).

Comment: My intentions are to keep the oscillations going. Isn't this what positive feedback is about? I guess, I forgot to add, I am a hobbyst electrical engineer and am not yet familiar with these symbols. If its possible, I would ask for a bit more in depth calculations.

Comment: So you intend to design an oscillator, correct? In this case, you must ensure that the oscillation condition (unity loop gain) is fulfilled for one singel frequency only!

Comment: Yes, I intent to design a 27 MHz oscillator using XTAL. How would I ensure that?

Comment: What is the source of the circuit? Either you have designed it by yourself or you have found it somewhere. In the first case - you know the task of each part, and in the second case you should read the circuit´s description.

Comment: The original circuit was meant for 12V, while I intend to power it from 6V. Which requires different values. I would also like to learn analyzing them, thats why I am asking.

Comment: Golaz, perhaps it helps to know that your circuit is a kind of Colpitt oscillator. Please try to find some relevant information. I think, this forum is not the right place to discuss the principle and the design in detail. At first, try to understand if and why it is able to oscillate (are you aware of the oscillation condition?).

Comment: Supplementing my last information: It is an improved version of the Colpitt oscillator which is called "Clapp oscillator".